# Putting Multiple Values from buttons in a Text Field

Tags: javascript

I have multiple sections of radio buttons to make choices from.

Currently, I have the page set up that when one of them is clicked, javascript takes the value from that button and updates it in the text field. But when I click both, the text area is replaced with only one of the values.

I am stuck trying to figure out how to multiple values in there. "fb" should sit in the string first and update if changed, then "uc" should go next, and so on for each section.

JS:

```
    $('input[name="fb"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[id="myText"]').val($(this).val());
});  

$('input[name="uc"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[id="myText"]').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$('input[name="fb"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[id="myText"]').val($('input[name="fb"]:checked').val()+$('input[name="uc"]:checked').val());
});  

$('input[name="uc"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[id="myText"]').val($('input[name="fb"]:checked').val()+$('input[name="uc"]:checked').val());
});
```

Comment: Worked! I was stuck on where the + sign should go.

Comment: Nice :D I'm glad i could help!

Comment: If it worked, you could accept this answer as the right one.